# x coordinate value after drag and drop event

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to get the x-value for a shape after drag and drop event by adding code below to a fiddle created by Lars Kotthoff; http://jsfiddle.net/EwGPu/1/ but I get the original position instead of the new position:

```
d3.selectAll('circle').each(function () {
console.log(d3.select(this).attr("cx"));
});
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't told us where you're adding the code, but in this example `cx` doesn't actually get set. Instead, the circles are positioned using `transform` (see the drag function). This is what you should be querying (or the data directly) to get the position. For example:

```
d3.selectAll("circle").each(function(e) {
        console.log(e.x);
});
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EwGPu/10/).

Comment: Perfect.  I'm actually trying to retrieve a date back from the x-axis after drag and drop event.  Your solution should help me get started.  Thanks

Comment: Lars   -Not as straight forward as I hoped.  The e approach didn't work with this example http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/jn9Vn/ but probably isn't the right way to get back a date based on x-value?  The fiddle doesn't have drag and drop yet.  Clickme changes the rect colour but doesn't work with fiddle for some reason!

Comment: You need to take the attribute that determines the x position: http://jsfiddle.net/jn9Vn/1/

Comment: should e.start be updated after drag event?  This example returns the initial values; http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/EVjw7/   I'm after the start date for the new position.  Any ideas?

Comment: You are changing the way the elements are positioned. Every time you do that, you need to update the way the coordinates are determined for what you want to do as well, see http://jsfiddle.net/EVjw7/1/

Comment: Fantastic.  Just what I wanted.